# GET data with Python from Dynamodb

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, get, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

This is my code where i am trying to get the data from an existing table of dynamodb through python code.

```
import boto3
import os
os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'] = 'us-east-1'



_TableName_ = "TablaLoraPF"

client = boto3.client('dynamodb')

DB = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = DB.Table(_TableName_)

response = table.get_item(
    Key={
        'seqno': "65909", 'data': "11"
    }
)
response["Item"]

print(response['Item'])
```

**your text**

I tried the code and this is what i get :

{'payload': {'metadata': {'reported': {'gws': [{'rssi': {'timestamp': Decimal('1667076850')}, 'snr': {'timestamp': Decimal('1667076850')}, 'ant': {'timestamp': Decimal('1667076850')}, 'gweui': {'timestamp': Decimal('1667076850')}, 'lon': {'timestamp': Decimal('1667076850')}, 'time': {'timestamp': Decimal('1667076850')}, 'lat': {'timestamp': Decimal('1667076850')}, 'ts': {'timestamp': Decimal('1667076850')}}], 'seqno': {'timestamp': Decimal('1667076850')}, 'data': {'timestamp': Decimal('1667076850')}, 'toa': {'timestamp': Decimal('1667076850')}, 'freq': {'timestamp': Decimal('1667076850')}, 'ack': {'timestamp': Decimal('1667076850')}, 'fcnt': {'timestamp': Decimal('1667076850')}, 'dr': {'timestamp': Decimal('1667076850')}, 'bat': {'timestamp': Decimal('1667076850')}, 'port': {'timestamp': Decimal('1667076850')}, 'EUI': {'timestamp': Decimal('1667076850')}, 'cmd': {'timestamp': Decimal('1667076850')}, '_id': {'timestamp': Decimal('1667076850')}, 'ts': {'timestamp': Decimal('1667076850')}}}, 'state': {'reported': {'gws': [{'rssi': Decimal('-107'), 'snr': Decimal('7'), 'ant': Decimal('0'), 'gweui': 'B827EBFFFFCF03ED', 'lon': Decimal('-74.868961'), 'time':
'2022-10-24T23:17:27.942418Z', 'lat': Decimal('11.023132'), 'ts': Decimal('1667076849799')}], 'seqno': Decimal('65909'), 'data': '11', 'toa': Decimal('1155'), 'freq': Decimal('868500000'), 'ack': False, 'fcnt': Decimal('6'), 'dr': 'SF12 BW125 4/5', 'bat': Decimal('255'), 'port': Decimal('8'), 'EUI': 'BE7A00000000056D', 'cmd': 'gw', '_id': '635d92f25390de5ad9600ba0', 'ts': Decimal('1667076849799')}}, 'version': Decimal('248'), 'timestamp': Decimal('1667076850')}, **'seqno': '65909', 'data': '11'}**

The code returns me all this data but I ONLY want the bold part, exactly this  (**'seqno': '65909', 'data': '11'}**)

I attached an image of my dynamodb table, i only want to print the data fron the columns seqno and data, not payload [image: I attached an image of my dynamodb table, i only want to print the data fron the columns seqno and data, not payload] but i dont know how. please helppp

Comment: Not sure I understand - you want the exact data that you pass in your query? If you have that, why are you querying? Btw

Comment: You are right, I wasnt noticing that, so, this is my new code => 
import boto3
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('TablaLoraPF')
response  = table.scan(ProjectionExpression = 'data'  )
data = response['Items']
for x in range(80):
    print(data[x])
As you can see i am using now scan the data but as i only want the items from the data column i am using projectioExpression but i got this error =>An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the GetItem operation: Invalid ProjectionExpression: Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: data

Comment: It says so in the error. The attribute name (or column name if you like) you use i.e. "data" is a reserved keyword. Change that attribute name to something else like "data1" and that error should go away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you need to specify `ProjectionExpression`.

```
response = table.get_item(
    Key={
        'seqno': "65909", 'data': "11"
    },
    ProjectionExpression = '#data', 
    ExpressionAttributeNames = {
         '#d':'data'
    }
)
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html#DDB-GetItem-request-ProjectionExpression

However, my question to you is why do you only want to return the columns you already know which seem to be your PK/SK?

Comment: Hello Lee! Actually, WHAT I NEED IS TO SCAN OR GET THE COLUMNS OF DATA from the dynamodb table. Because those items are been received from a connection with a LoRa Gateway. But now i am trying  what you said and this is what i got  when i am calling seqno and data columns (I NEED TO GET THE ITEMS FROM THE DATA COLUMN but i only get the items from the seqno column) 

botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the GetItem operation: Invalid ProjectionExpression: ** Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: data**

Comment: You simply need to use ExpressionAttributeNames, i've updated my answer.

Comment: yes thank you! and according to your question. I have changed my code, this is the new one

import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('TablaLoraPF')
response  = table.scan(ProjectionExpression = "#d",
                       ExpressionAttributeNames = {'#d': 'data'})
data = response['Items']
for x in range(10):
    print(data[x])

Btw do you have any how i can to update the scannig from the dynamo table but in ascendent or descendent order?  
note: the update is because i send data from a electrical meter through LoraWan and dynamodb is my database.

Comment: It's not clear if my answers are helpful?

Comment: yes it was very helpful. I fixed the code and it worked really well

Comment: If you can mark the answer as accepted that would be great.